# Running Nginx as non-root user

Tags: php, nginx

I compiled Nginx from sources.

In the configuration file, I set up Nginx to be ran as nobody user.

However, the output of the `ps aux` is as following:

```
root      1691  0.0  0.0  27872   948 ?        Ss   11:28   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nobody    1692  0.0  0.0  28284  1852 ?        S    11:28   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

As you can see, master process is being ran as root user.

Is there everything ok with the configuration?

Cheers, Stojko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  That's how it's supposed to work: the master process does the bind to the privileged port 80.  The worker processes are spawned by the master the handle actual HTTP requests, and then drop privileges (to user "nobody" in your case).  Web documents (and directories) will need to be accessible by user "nobody".

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly as I thought, just needed advanced user confirmation :) Thanks for your input.

Comment: Just to note, Apache works the same way (a master process running as root that binds to port 80, and non-root worker processes that serve the actual HTTP requests): http://serverfault.com/questions/355223/centos-httpd-running-as-both-root-and-apache-user/355230#355230

Comment: All ports under 1024 requires root privileges, am I right? I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: Yes, ports under 1024 require root privs to bind to them.